# iOS - Resuming music player from my app after recording session is done

Tags: ios, video, video-recording

I have a recording session in my app that cancels background music that is playing currently.

I want this music to resume as soon as my recording session is finished. I saw that system Camera app does that as soon as you leave if you were playing music in system Music app.

I saw Snapchat app doing even better thing with continuing with playing the background music while recording. Is there a way to achieve the same goal as snapchat does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code based on the framework you are using

### AVFoundation

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] 
    setActive:YES 
    withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation 
    error:nil];
```

### MediaPlayer

```
MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
[mp play];
```

Comment: To start my recording session I am using `AVCaptureSession` method `addOutput` with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` object. As soon as `addOutput` gets called, background music gets killed, and what I do is I call `removeOutput` when video recording is done. Tried your code with MPMusicPlayerController and it continues system playback. But what if I want to continue background playback from 3rd party app that was playing(for example radio app)?